# Errors opening a file in c

Tags: c, linux, file-io

currently I'm having problems with the function below trying to open a file, no matter what I give it the function can't seem to open the file. I'm currently passing in "./input.txt" which is a file in the same directory as the executable.  Is there anything blatantly wrong with the code that you guys can see?

```
FILE* openInputFile(char* inputFileName) 
{
    FILE* ifp= NULL;

    printf("%s\n", inputFileName);
    ifp = fopen(inputFileName, "rb");

    if(ifp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening input file.\n");              
    }

    return ifp;
}
```

Comment: are you on windows or unix?

Comment: No; there are minor nits that could be picked, but nothing major that I see.  Your problem may be that your process's current directory is not the directory you think it is.  The current directory will be the current directory of the shell that launches the process, not the directory that the code is found in.  You could print the error from `errno` via `strerror()` to see what is going wrong, but it probably just says "no such file or directory".  You could use [`getcwd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) to print out the working directory.

Comment: @ojblass: tags say 'Linux'.

Comment: What are the permission bits on the input file?  What does 'ls -lat' print?

Comment: Double check file permissions. Make sure the running user has read access.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Would be useful to put some printf's in there with actual error codes.

Comment: Do a `strlen(inputFileName);`.  You expect the result to be 11.  However, I'm guessing you'll get a length of 12 or 13.

Comment: The cod works fine. you need to do some operation on the file so that is confirms that the file is open. try either reading or writing to the file.

Comment: change printf after the error to perror - this will explain the failure

Comment: yes as pm100 says always use perror for finding out what error has occurred

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to memory stored on the stack. When the function exits the memory is freed and you are pointing to unallocated memory. You must pass the pointer in as a parameter to return the file name:

```
void openInputFile(char* inputFileName, FILE* ifp)
{
    FILE* ifp= NULL;

    printf("%s\n", inputFileName);
    ifp = fopen(inputFileName, "rb");

    if(ifp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening input file.\n");              
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you have an extra `FILE *ifp` declaration inside of your method.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the code. It works fine. Double check the file exists where you think it exists. If it exists, make sure the file permissions allow for the user running the program to read the file.

```
[user@localhost]$ vim test.c
[user@localhost]$ gcc test.c -o test
[user@localhost]$ ./test
./input.txt
Error opening input file: No such file or directory
[user@localhost]$ touch ./input.txt
[user@localhost]$ ./test
./input.txt
[user@localhost]$ cat test.c
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE* openInputFile(char* inputFileName) 
{
    FILE* ifp= NULL;

    printf("%s\n", inputFileName);
    ifp = fopen(inputFileName, "rb");

    if(ifp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening input file");              
    }

    return ifp;
}

int main(int argc, char * arv[]){
    openInputFile("./input.txt");
}
```

```
[user@localhost]$ ls -la ./input.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 0 Feb 19 15:37 ./input.txt
```

Comment: also be careful if you dont have a memory issue in some other part of your program.  You can set watches on variables in gcc.